# Change Data in List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Based on the below code, is there a way in Linq execute an expression to change names in a list?  Is it better to use a for loop rather than LINQ?  The application is pulling in a a lot of data from a database using EF and must change a few items in a list.  I am able to change the test string but the the names array.

```
public class NameChanges
{
    public string OriginalName { get; set; }
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}

string[] names = { "Burke", "Connor", "Frank",
                   "Everett", "Albert", "George",
                   "Harris", "David" };

string test = "some example names that can be replaced: John, Albert, David, Bobby";


    List<NameChanges> nameChanges = new List<NameChanges>();
    nameChanges.Add(new NameChanges() { OriginalName = "Connor", NewName = "Jonnor" });
    nameChanges.Add(new NameChanges() { OriginalName = "Albert", NewName = "Jalbert" });
    nameChanges.Add(new NameChanges() { OriginalName = "David", NewName = "Javid" });

    nameChanges.ForEach(x => test = test.Replace(x.OriginalName, x.NewName));
```

Comment: " optimize this expression " what would be your criterion for optimization? runtime? memory consumption? readability?

Comment: From what I can recall, theres not a lot of difference. LINQ actually compiles down to the underlying foreach loops anyway. LINQ is visually nicer to look at ( in my opinion) but not quicker! The foreach is easier to debug as well.

Comment: @MongZhu I will change to simply "make it work".  To change a list of names based on conditions.

Comment: @Wheels73 Yes I think so too.  Problem is I cannot change the list.  Or have not yet figured out a way to.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and whether it has anything to do with EF.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft not much to do with EF, more on solving the problem of changing names in list efficiently

Comment: Thank you for answers so far

Comment: " I cannot change the list. " I am confused. In your code you replace elements in a string... which list do you want to change again?

Comment: @MongZhu yes I did, I would like to change 'names' array

Comment: @WilliamHumphries LINQ is a *query* language. It doesn't change anything. It has **no** modification methods. Your code calls `List.ForEach`, not any LINQ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change items in array so easily when you iterate by it with linq.

I can propose 2 solutions:

```
string[] names = { "Burke", "Connor", "Frank",
               "Everett", "Albert", "George",
               "Harris", "David" };

Dictionary<string, string> replaceRules =
    new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Connor", "Jonnor" },
            { "Albert", "Jalbert" },
            { "David", "Javid" },
        };

// Solution1: Get new IEnumerable with 
// replaced names which can be converted to array or list
IEnumerable<string> replacedNames = 
    names.Select(n => replaceRules.ContainsKey(n) ? replaceRules[n] : n);


// Solution2: Change values in original array
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    if (replaceRules.ContainsKey(names[i]))
    {
        names[i] = replaceRules[names[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that Solution 1 will create a whole new object, so if you are dealing with very large arrays then this could increase memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer for this would be to use the simpliest solution.

Why does this need to be done in a LINQ expression, personally I would just have a simple for loop

You could make this into some complex LINQ expression, but how would that benifit you? Does it make it more readable? Probably not. Does it make it faster? Again probably not or possibly even the same speed.

I think you are possibly over thinking this, I always like to refer to this quote:

> Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.

Answer (score 0):

While LINQ has methods for operating over records, those serve mainly for lookup.
So you technically can call even the most popular `where` operator, as follows:

```
collectionInstance.Where(item=>{ModifyItem(item); return false;});
```

But that'll really be confusing to the readers of your code. Instead, just go with your update using a simple for operator.

**On a side note**, please don't judge me here, as I'm not commenting about whether doing so is right or wrong. There are way too many parameters to decide on a good way to update data.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do with Select, like this:

```
nameChanges = nameChanges.Select(n => {n.OriginalName = n.NewName; return n;}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, why don't you create a dictionary of the names to change  . Then loop through your EF collection testing for targetName and replace with the corresponding value.

Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better solution

Comment: Sure it does. I am suggesting a solution and Mr Humphries agrees. Mark me down. See if I care.